# Действия по нажатию кнопки: вызвать функцию и изменить название кнопки

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qss, qpushbutton

Есть две кнопки (`к1`, `к2`) и одна функция (`func()`).

Содержимое функции :

```
    self.название_кнопки.setStyleSheet("""
        background-color: blue;
        border-style: outset;
        border-width: 2px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border-color: beige;
     """)
```

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы допустим, если я нажал `к1`, то вызвалась эта функция, и а месте названия кнопки было  **`"к1"`**?

---

**UPD**:

К сожалению работающего варианта нет, поэтому я здесь, но вот примерно  та конструкция о которой я говорю:

```
class Main_Wid(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, TextEditorDes.Ui_Form) :

   def __init__(self) :
       super().__init__()
       self.setupUi(self)
    
       self.closeButton.pressed.connect(self.pressed)
       self.openButton.pressed.connect(self.pressed)

   def pressed(self, button) :
       self.кнопка_которую_передают.setStyleSheet("""
        background-color: blue;
        border-style: outset;
        border-width: 2px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border-color: beige;
         """)
```

---

**TextEditorDes.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(600, 460)
        self.saveButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.saveButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 430, 75, 23))
        self.saveButton.setCheckable(False)
        self.saveButton.setChecked(False)
        self.saveButton.setDefault(False)
        self.saveButton.setObjectName("saveButton")
        self.openButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.openButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 430, 75, 23))
        self.openButton.setObjectName("openButton")
        self.MainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.MainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 580, 410))
        self.MainTextEdit.setObjectName("MainTextEdit")
        self.FileName = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.FileName.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 430, 101, 20))
        self.FileName.setObjectName("FileName")
        self.fileInfoButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.fileInfoButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 430, 75, 23))
        self.fileInfoButton.setObjectName("fileInfoButton")
        self.closeButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.closeButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 430, 75, 23))
        self.closeButton.setObjectName("closeButton")
        self.isSavedLineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.isSavedLineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 432, 51, 20))
        self.isSavedLineEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.isSavedLineEdit.setObjectName("isSavedLineEdit")
        self.themeButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.themeButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(516, 430, 75, 23))
        self.themeButton.setObjectName("themeButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Editor"))
        self.saveButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Save"))
        self.openButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Open"))
        self.FileName.setText(_translate("Form", "None"))
        self.fileInfoButton.setText(_translate("Form", "File info"))
        self.closeButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Close file"))
        self.isSavedLineEdit.setText(_translate("Form", " No saved"))
        self.themeButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Dark"))
```

Comment: Можно сделать все что хотите, но если вы хотите получать быстрые и правильные ответы, предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример того что у вас есть.

Comment: опубликуйте модуль `TextEditorDes.py`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Скрытая ошибка заключается в том, что вы не правильно выбираете класс родителя, когда создаете форму в `Qt Designer`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

2. По сути вопроса:

> QObject *QObject::sender()
>
> Возвращает указатель на объект, который отправил сигнал.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

#from TextEditorDes import Ui_Form

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(600, 460)
        self.saveButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.saveButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 430, 75, 23))
        self.saveButton.setCheckable(False)
        self.saveButton.setChecked(False)
        self.saveButton.setDefault(False)
        self.saveButton.setObjectName("saveButton")
        self.openButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.openButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 430, 75, 23))
        self.openButton.setObjectName("openButton")
        self.MainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.MainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 580, 410))
        self.MainTextEdit.setObjectName("MainTextEdit")
        self.FileName = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.FileName.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 430, 101, 20))
        self.FileName.setObjectName("FileName")
        self.fileInfoButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.fileInfoButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 430, 75, 23))
        self.fileInfoButton.setObjectName("fileInfoButton")
        self.closeButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.closeButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 430, 75, 23))
        self.closeButton.setObjectName("closeButton")
        self.isSavedLineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.isSavedLineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 432, 51, 20))
        self.isSavedLineEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.isSavedLineEdit.setObjectName("isSavedLineEdit")
        self.themeButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.themeButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(516, 430, 75, 23))
        self.themeButton.setObjectName("themeButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Editor"))
        self.saveButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Save"))
        self.openButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Open"))
        self.FileName.setText(_translate("Form", "None"))
        self.fileInfoButton.setText(_translate("Form", "File info"))
        self.closeButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Close file"))
        self.isSavedLineEdit.setText(_translate("Form", " No saved"))
        self.themeButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Dark"))
        

#class Main_Wid(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, TextEditorDes.Ui_Form) :   # QMainWindow <-> Ui_MainWindow
class Main_Wid(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form) :                      # QWidget     <-> Ui_Form       !!!!
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.closeButton.pressed.connect(self.pressed_func)
        self.openButton.pressed.connect(self.pressed_func)

#    def pressed_func(self, button):  
    def pressed_func(self) :
        sender = self.sender()                                    # <---
#       self.кнопка_которую_передают.setStyleSheet("""
        sender.setStyleSheet(""" 
            background-color: blue;
            border-style: outset;
            border-width: 2px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            border-color: beige;
        """)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main_Wid()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]