# Как изменить время в QDateTimeEdit

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qdatetime, qdatetimeedit

Имеется переменная `date`, которая имеет тип `QDateTimeEdit`.

`date.dateTime()` имеет тип `QDateTime`.

Как добавить или вычесть несколько дней или часов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MyWin(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        lblCurrentDateTime   = QLabel()
        self.lblDateTimeEdit = QLabel()
        btn_days = QPushButton("DateTime + 7 days")
        btn_days.clicked.connect(self.editDateDay_days)
        btn_hours = QPushButton("DateTime + 2 hours")
        btn_hours.clicked.connect(self.editDateDay_hours)

        lblCurrentDateTime.setText(
            QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString('yyyy MM dd hh:mm:ss'))

        self.dateTimeBegin = QDateTimeEdit()
        self.dt = self.dateTimeBegin.dateTime().currentDateTime()

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(lblCurrentDateTime)
        lay.addWidget(self.lblDateTimeEdit)
        lay.addWidget(btn_days)
        lay.addWidget(btn_hours)
        
    def editDateDay_days(self):
        self.dateTimeBegin.setDateTime(self.dt.addDays(7))
        self.dt = self.dt.addDays(7)
        currentTime = self.dateTimeBegin.dateTime().toString(
            'yyyy MM dd hh:mm:ss')
        self.lblDateTimeEdit.setText(
            self.dateTimeBegin.dateTime().toString('yyyy MM dd hh:mm:ss'))

    def editDateDay_hours(self):
        self.dateTimeBegin.setDateTime(self.dt.addSecs(1*60*60*2))
        self.dt = self.dt.addSecs(1*60*60*2)
        currentTime = self.dateTimeBegin.dateTime().toString(
            'yyyy MM dd hh:mm:ss')
        self.lblDateTimeEdit.setText(
            self.dateTimeBegin.dateTime().toString('yyyy MM dd hh:mm:ss'))


if __name__ =="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло

Comment: @helldrg   Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: в моем случае не помогло, расписал в UDP

Comment: @helldrg если вам действительно нужна помощь, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Помогло, спасибо большое

Comment: @helldrg в вашем примере есть скрытая ошибка.  Замените строку `class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Form):` на строку `class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):`, а также замените `addDays` на `addSecs`

Comment: `addDays` на `addSecs` да, я смотрел на минуты, а менялись дни точнее года =) А в чем разница `QMainWindow` и` QWidget`?

Comment: @helldrg QMainWindow имеет свой собственный макет https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework

Comment: @helldrg  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1104103

Comment: Спасибо большое